# In SQL Server, deleting nodes using .modify() XQuery taking 38 minutes to execute

Tags: sql-server, xml, xquery

In SQL Server, I have a stored procedure with XML type temporary variable, and I am doing a delete operation on that variable. When I am running this stored procedure in my local VM which has 4 cores and 6 GB RAM, it takes 24 seconds to execute. But when I am running the same stored procedure in server with 40 cores and 128 GB RAM, this delete statement is taking more than 38 minutes to execute. The whole stored procedure gets hanged at this delete statement for 38 minutes. After commenting out the delete statement, the stored procedure executes in 8 seconds on the server. How I can fix this performance issue. Is there something wrong in ther SQL server configuration?

```
DECLARE @PaymentData AS XML

SET @PaymentData = .....(Main XML Query)

SET @PaymentData.modify('delete //*[not(node())]')
```

@Mikael: Below is the execution plan for shredding into rows solution on server (with 40 cores and 128 GB RAM)
[image]
[image]
And Below is the excecution plan in my local VM(with 4 cores and 6 GB RAM):
[image]
[image]

Comment: If the amount of data in both cases is comparable, you can try `option (maxdop)` to reduce the degree of parallelism.

Comment: What versions of SQL Server are you using? Are they the same on both servers? Is the size and content of the XML the same? Does the query plans look the same?

Comment: @RogerWolf I tried adding option(maxdop 1) to the query, but its same performance

Comment: @MikaelEriksson: Both the environments have SQL Server 2008 R2. And the the size of the XML content is exactly equal (around 12,000 records).

Comment: Ok, how many of those 12,000 nodes in the XML is empty and will be removed by the delete?

Comment: @MikaelEriksson: As the XML content there are 12,000 records and each record has around 32 nodes, out of which two nodes are empty. So total of 24,000 nodes needs to be deleted.

Comment: Is the execution plan the same on Physiscal and VM machine?

Comment: Os the number if ondexes to be updated tha same on VM and on Physical server? Is the indexes size the same?

Comment: @Giova: Currently there is no indexing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On my machine the delete took 1 hour 25 minutes and gave me this not so pretty query plan.

[image]

This plan finds all empty nodes (the ones to be deleted) and stores those in a Table Spool. Then for each node in the entire document there is a check if that node is present in the spool (Nested Loops (Left Semi Join)) and if it is that node is excluded from the final result (Merge join (Left Anti Semi Join)). The xml is then rebuilt from the nodes in the UDX operator and assigned to the variable. The table spool is not indexed so for each node that needs to be checked there will be a scan of the entire spool (or until a match is found).

That essentially means the performance of this algorithm is `O(n*d)` where `n` is the total number of nodes and `d` is the total number or deleted nodes.

There are a couple of possible workarounds.

First and perhaps the best is if you could modify your XML query to not produce the empty nodes in the first place. Totally possible if you create the XML with `for xml` and perhaps not possible if you already have parts of the XML stored in a table.

Another option is to shred the XML on `Row` (see sample XML below), put the result in a table variable, modify the XML in the table variable and then recreate the combined XML.

```sql
declare @T table(PaymentData xml);

insert into @T 
select T.X.query('.')
from @PaymentData.nodes('Row') as T(X);

update @T
set PaymentData.modify('delete //*[not(node())]');

select T.PaymentData as '*'
from @T as T
for xml path('');
```

[image]

This will give you the performance characteristic of `O(n*s*d)` where `n` is the number of `row` nodes, `s` is the number of sub-nodes per `row` node and `d` is the number of deleted rows per `row` node.

A third option that I really can't recommend is to use an undocumented trace flag that removes the use of a spool in the plan. You can try it out in test or you can perhaps capture the plan generated and use it in a plan guide.

```sql
declare @T table(PaymentData xml);

insert into @T values(@PaymentData);

update @T 
set PaymentData.modify('delete //*[not(node())]')
option (querytraceon 8690);

select @PaymentData = PaymentData
from @T;
```

Query plan with trace flag:

[image]

Instead of 1 hour 25 minutes, this version took 4 seconds on my computer.

Shredding the XML to multiple rows to the table variable took in total 6 seconds to execute.

Not having to delete any rows at all is of course the fastest.

Sample data, 12000 nodes with 32 subnodes where 2 is empty if you want to try this at home.

```sql
declare @PaymentData as xml;

set @PaymentData = (
                   select top(12000) 
                     1 as N1, 1 as N2, 1 as N3, 1 as N4, 1 as N5, 1 as N6, 1 as N7, 1 as N8, 1 as N9, 1 as N10, 
                     1 as N11, 1 as N12, 1 as N13, 1 as N14, 1 as N15, 1 as N16, 1 as N17, 1 as N18, 1 as N19, 1 as N20, 
                     1 as N21, 1 as N22, 1 as N23, 1 as N24, 1 as N25, 1 as N26, 1 as N27, 1 as N28, 1 as N29, 1 as N30,
                     '' as N31,
                     '' as N32
                   from sys.columns as c1, sys.columns as c2
                   for xml path('Row')
                   );
```

Note: I have no idea why it only took 24 seconds to execute on one of your servers. I would advise you to recheck that the XML actually is identical. Or why not test using the XML sample I have provided for you.

**Update:**

For the shredding version the problem with the spool in the delete query could be moved to the shredding query instead leaving you with about the same bad performance. That is however not always true. I have seen plans where there is no spool and plans where there are a spool and I don't know why it is there sometimes and why it is not at other times.

I have also found that if you use a temp table instead with `insert ... into` I don't get the spool in the shredding query.

```sql
select T.X.query('.') as PaymentData
into #T
from @PaymentData.nodes('Row') as T(X);

update #T
set PaymentData.modify('delete //*[not(node())]');
```

Comment: I tried running above solutions with the sample data provided by you, but the performance is same. When I tried the solution of shredding into rows(in total it took 1 hour 9 seconds to execute), and this time the insert statement took 81% of the execution time. And delete statement took 18%. Is there something wrong in SQL server configuration (although it has 40 cores and 128 GB RAM). And of course all your solutions are working perfectly in my local VM which has 4 cores and 6 GB RAM.

Comment: @Rakesh I would very much like to see the xml version of the actual execution plan from your fast local VM for the original statement `SET @PaymentData.modify('delete //*[not(node())]') ` on my generated test data. You can use http://pastebin.com/ and post the link to the XML query plan here in a comment or you can update your question with the link to the plan. It would also be interesting to see the plans for the shredding solution I have given you from both servers. Note: The query cost percentage has nothing to do with how a query perform. They are just an estimate even in the actual plan.

Comment: I have uploaded the screenshot of execution plan below the question.

Comment: @Rakesh The XML version would be so much better.

Comment: I see that the issue with the spool is moved to the shredding query instead probably making that one the slow query instead of the delete query.

Comment: Yes exactly, it moved to shredding query. And not sure why, I am not able to open pastebin.com from my computer. Anyother site where I can upload the xml or I can mail you as well.

Comment: @Rakesh I have update the answer with something you can try. I also see the bad spool in the shredding query and at some point in time (I can't recreate it) I did not.

Comment: These are link of the Execution plan xml: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9RzUHmJoL65UGYwQ2lzUnp2NUk/view?usp=sharing and another one   https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9RzUHmJoL65ZWVDbWc0TzRacnM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Rakesh You have different versions of SQL Server. VM is 11.0.3128.0 (SQL Server 2012) and your Server is 10.50.4000.0 (SQL Server 2008 R2). For me, the shredding to a table variable gets a spool in SQL Server 2008 and not in SQL Server 2012. The update directly on the XML variable gets a spool in all versions.

Comment: Perfect solution Mikael. Solution of using temp table worked !!! Now the query executed in 10 seconds. Thanks a lot Mikael and you are Brilliant. Really appreciate your help and time that you devoted for this analysis. And I am also curious about why there is so much difference between the server and my local VM, although the server is much much powerful than my local VM.

Comment: @Rakesh The issue with the spool in the shredding query in SQL Server 2008 is a bug and is fixed if you have the update in place and enable trace flag 4130. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/957205